# Shuffle a ctype array in python

Tags: python, arrays, ctypes

I want to shuffle a ctype array. When I try the `random.shuffle(myArray)` I get an error (`builtins.ValueError: PyObject is NULL`)

```
    import ctypes
    import random

    def shuffleArray():
        size = 10
        myArray = (size*ctypes.py_object)()
        random.shuffle(myArray)
        for i in range(0,size):
        myArray[i] = i
        print(myArray[i])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random.shuffle` works by simply swapping the items of random index values. There's no problem if you first initialize the array, so as to not dereference a null pointer:

```
>>> import ctypes, random
>>> my_array = (10 * ctypes.py_object)(*range(10))
>>> random.shuffle(my_array)
>>> my_array[:]
[5, 0, 4, 8, 6, 3, 7, 1, 2, 9]
```

I have no idea why you need `py_object` instead of a regular C type. That's unusual. Unless you really need to pass an array of Python objects to a library, you should be using a regular C type such as `c_long`, `c_double`, etc. These types convert the value of a Python object to a C data type.

---

Here's a  bit more on `py_object` (type 'O'). It's a simple pointer type, like `c_void_p` (type 'P'). By simple type, I mean it's a subclass of `_ctypes._SimpleCData` instead of `_ctypes._Pointer`, so it has a `value` attribute instead of `contents`. A `py_object` points specifically at a Python object, which in CPython is the object's `id`. The constructor keeps a reference to the object in the `_objects` attribute. This prevents the referenced object from being garbage collected.

```
>>> obj = 'abc'
>>> pyobj = ctypes.py_object(obj)

>>> pyobj._objects is obj
True
>>> addr = ctypes.c_size_t.from_buffer(pyobj).value 
>>> addr == id(obj)
True
```

The [type 'O' `GETFUNC`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1111) (used to get an array item, struct field, or function call result) returns a new reference to the Python object. But it first checks for `NULL`. That's the source of the `ValueError` you're getting. In contrast, the [type 'P' `GETFUNC`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3a1db0d2747e/Modules/_ctypes/cfield.c#l1580) of a `c_void_p` simply returns `None` in this case:

```
>>> arr = (ctypes.c_void_p * 5)()
>>> random.shuffle(arr) # silly this is
>>> arr[:]
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ctypes
import random
def shuffleArray():
    size = 10
    myArray = (size * ctypes.c_int)()
    random.shuffle(myArray)
    for i in range(0, size):
        myArray[i] = i
        print(myArray[i])
shuffleArray()
```

I think you should use `ctypes.c_int` instead of `ctypes.py_object`.

ctypes defines a number of primitive C compatible data types.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html